# Which is the best way to configure auth between two apis using Django rest framework?

Tags: django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm using DRF for developing an API and I want to consume this API with another API and with an app. For the second API, how can I develop an API authentication? I think that using JWT is not good because I'll need to save the token on the consumer Api and keep refreshing it.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to avoid refresh of JWT token you can configure that at the settings.py

```
JWT_AUTH = {
'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': False}
```

You may use the package djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
If you don't want to use JWT at all you can still use the basic authentication rather than token based authentication.

Your authorization header would then have a format as follows:

```
Basic cG9pc29uaXZAYXJraGFtLmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

The basic authentication will not change until you change the password.

But since you were asking which is best, I would recommend JWT with expiry for the right security reasons. But if you take out expiry from your equation JWT and Basic Auth just as same except that JWT can still be expired and you can demand reauthorization without the consumer changing the password.

Please note you can use basic and JWT authentication hand in hand.

For your second API's internal consumption you can use basic auth even if JWT is implemented.